# How to create Multiple Gallery in an activity dynamically?

Tags: android, image, image-gallery, android-gallery, android-adapter

I want to display multiple Gallery in my Application. The number of gallery depends on the input which i get while running. Im confused to create it dynamically.

Please help me. Following are the idea's which im planning to do.

1. Creating Gallery array using the input.length.
2. Assigning same **Image Adapter** class for all galleries.

Here are my questions

1. Will it work if i apply same Image Adapter for all Galeries?
2. If so i have Different array to store the images, how i will assign Image Adapter to take which array?
3. Is there any other simple way to implement it?

Thanks in advance